# Manage PHP time function

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I am using godaddy hosting service and I can manage local time, I have to use the server default time that is America/Phoenix.

Even if i am using `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");` 
function in my config file then also there is no difference in time and godaddy people are not ready to help me with, I am tired of calling this guys but no response, I hate them all.

Is there any means I can get my local time using any function or any external API?

I am using this code

```
       //set time zone india
       date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
       $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
       echo "The current server timezone is: " . $timezone;
       $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
       echo $date."<br>";
```

and the output that I am getting is

```
    The current server timezone is: Asia/Kolkata05/14/2014 12:06:26 am
```

Even if it is 4:38 pm here...

Comment: If using `date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");` isn't fixing the problem, then you're probably using it in the wrong place

Comment: get the response of date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); and see if it is returning true.

Comment: Well, no hosting support in the world could possibly help you with your programming questions, unless you'd be willing to pay consulting fees. Now, can you please edit the question and explain what " there is no difference in time" means? Changing the default time zone is never going to change the system clock or anything like that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I beg to differ :p I've helped clients solve tricky programming issues ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I might also call a taxi for a customer, but that's still beyond my job responsibilities as programmer ;-P

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yeah, fair enough XD It's not something that is done for every little thing, but our support guys do tend to genuinely try to solve problems. I was a customer here for four years before getting a job here, so I've got experience on both sides ^_^

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You're stopping at nothing with the promotion, eh? :p

Comment: @asprin I have no shame! :p Nah, I didn't mean to promote quite this much, just sort of... got carried away.

Answer (score 0):

`date_default_timezone_set` should work for PHP functions like `date`, however I'm going to hazard a guess that you're having problems with date/time elements in a database such as MySQL.

I know I've had similar problems before, when trying to get everything on UTC instead of Europe/London...

When you've established the connection to your database, be sure to run this query:

```
SET time_zone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
```

This, in addition to `date_default_timezone_set`, should solve your problems. However, if you're using `DATETIME` columns, then those will not be fixed. `TIMESTAMP` columns will be automagically fixed to the new timezone because they are saved as UTC internally and converted upon retrieval.

Comment: Huh. That is strange. Can you try `echo date("e")`? This will output the timezone used internally by `date`.

Comment: It is giving me output of America/Phoenix on date('e') and while using echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s a'); it is giving me 2014-05-13 12:21:04 pm, but in Phoenix it is 4:20 am

Comment: @sourabhkasliwal 12:21pm is GMT right now, which is neither America/Phoenix nor Asia/Kolkata. I have no idea what's going on, but it's definitely a problem with the server, not your code...

Comment: But these Godaddy people they are not going listen to me, I am sick of using there services, is there any other alternative..

Comment: Yes, see my profile and find the link in my bio ;) Hey, you can even have your site migrated for free if you join! Heck, I'll even give you a promo code: `hypermode` for 10% off. Have fun!

Comment: Ok, I will let you know Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't touch `date_default_timezone_set`. The proper way to do that would be to use DateTimeZone object. Something like this:

```
    $now = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
    echo $now->format(\DateTime::ATOM);
```

So, the idea is that you create an object in a timezone of server and then convert it to your timezone

Comment: Well, `date_default_timezone_set()` exists so you don't need the scatter the same initialisation code all around your codebase. Your method just makes it messier.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario my method is extremely explicit which makes it reliable. the problem with `date_default_timezone_set` is that it can be modified in-between

Comment: @JimiDini : it is not working correct it is giving me wrong time